# How to reference a value from the following dictionary in a list of dictionaries

Tags: c#

I currently have created a `List<Dictionaries<string, string>>`

The data within is in the following format

```
{  
     ["Cell1"] = "10:00",
     ["Cell2"] = "Player1Name",
     ["Cell3"] = "P1Score",
     ["Cell4"] = "P1ImpliedChance",
},
{  
     ["Cell1"] = "Player2Name",
     ["Cell2"] = "P2Score",
     ["Cell3"] = "P2ImpliedChance",
},
{  
     ["Cell1"] = "12:00",
     ["Cell2"] = "Player1Name",
     ["Cell3"] = "P1Score",
     ["Cell4"] = "P1ImpliedChance",
},
{  
     ["Cell1"] = "Player2Name",
     ["Cell2"] = "P2Score",
     ["Cell3"] = "P2ImpliedChance",
},
```

What I want to achieve **in a new List** is outlined below..

```
{  
     ["Cell1"] = "10:00",
     ["Cell2"] = "Player1Name",
     ["Cell3"] = "Player2Name",
     ["Cell4"] = "P1ImpliedChance",
     ["Cell5"] = "P2ImpliedChance",
},
{  
     ["Cell1"] = "12:00",
     ["Cell2"] = "Player1Name",
     ["Cell3"] = "Player2Name",
     ["Cell4"] = "P1ImpliedChance",
     ["Cell5"] = "P2ImpliedChance",
},
```

Now, were this PHP, it would be a quite simple affair. It would just be an array which I would loop as follows and then simply increment the key to return the values I need.

```
<?php
foreach($List as $k){
    $output[$k]["Cell1"] = $k["Cell1"];
    $output[$k]["Cell2"] = $k["Cell2"];
    $output[$k]["Cell3"] = $k["Cell3"];
    $output[$k]["Cell4"] = ($k+1)["Cell1"];
    $output[$k]["Cell5"] = ($k+1)["Cell3"];
}
```

However, having searched extensively, I can find no clear-cut method of referencing the next dictionary in the list.

It seems it is not possible for me to change the original data structure as that's how the program receives it.

I can find no way to refer to an index and indeed I'm fairly sure the property would not exist anyway. Have I overlooked something?

Comment: Hey there! I am trying to figure out how come the data comes in so scrambled so that you are left to arrange it in such a way you described? So the input is Cell2 and Cell3 are PlayerName and Score or Score or ImpliedChance as keys/values, but the end result requries it to be 5 keys arranged in your described order?

Comment: I can't understand what the PHP version is doing but it looks like you want to merge each pair of dictionaries into a single dictionary? Why is `Cell3` of the first result `"Player2Name"` and not `"P1Score"`?

Comment: coming from PHP you don't seem to be fully grasping that C# is an object-oriented language. My recommendation is not to have a list of dictionaries, but use a list of  your own concrete class (e.g. `List<MyClass>`), it will make your code much easier to understand.

Comment: Merging would suffice. I don't need all values to transfer but I'm not sure that's important anyway. Just being able to reference the following dict was what I was after really.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can jsut use for loop and the index in the list. Lets say your varible is:

`List<Dictionaries<string, string>> yourLsit`

And you can loop through like below

```
for(int i=0; i< yourList.Count; i+=2)
{

    var curItem = yourList[i];
    var nextItem = i+1 < yourList.Count ? yourList[i+1] : default(Dictionaries<string, string>);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed but could find no reference to.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the list contains an even number of items? Otherwise this could throw an argument out of range exception.

Comment: @Knoop, I assumed from the OPs sample in the question. And it seems my assumption is correct. But yeah `i+1 < yourList.Count-1` check would prevent this issue.